# Calling a Web Service Within the Same Project

Tags: java, web-services

I have a project that contains a JAX-WS web service I've made. Within the same project, I am adding a user interface that calls it's own web service. What is the best way to approach making the call?

Many tutorials I've seen show using wsimport to generate proxy classes. Is it possible to reuse the existing classes in the project which define the service? Or do I need to generate a whole new set of classes just to call it?

Comment: Can you please provide more context like why from same project you need to make a web service call ? If it is a user interface in the same project , it can call directly the methods and classes which the web service is using for processing request. I feel you may need to decouple your web service request processing which will let you reuse the code.

Comment: The service is basically used to search logs. The app is being run in multiple environments, each containing multiple application servers. The idea is that if a user wants to search environment X, from environment Y, that Y will call the service of each application server on X and collate the results, displaying them to the user. The app is aware via configs of all the other instances of the app.